# Mobile application sharing the same data with the website

Tags: php, mobile-application

I'm totally new about mobile application development and i'm getting really confused about few things.

I'm actually developing web application under zend framework 2 (php framework) and Zend studio (IDE).

So to not starting all over again i want to make a mobile app (for learning purpose) with ZF2 and Zend studio.

I've been following that [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJVh6myWRRM).

So i'm not sure to understand how the data are stored. Until now i have used MySQL with phpmyadmin for my web applications.

From what i understand, i need to use a cloud server such as Parse, phpcloud or else, am i right?

My question is, how the website and the mobile app will share the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typically you will have to write web services that will expose a few methods which in turn will get the required data you want to share.

So your connectivity should look like Mobile APP --> Web Service --> DB

Make sure to thrown in some kind of authentication to avoid abuse of your web services. The webservice can be deployed on the same server that is hosting the website

One more way is to access the mysql database directly from your mobile application . This is **NOT** recommended because essentially you are exposing your DB to the world. This is OK in case of a corporate application which will only work within your company network or with a controlled environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PaaS like Heroku or Openshift to host your web application. But The web application must also expose a set of web services, which can be used to send and receive information to and from the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tutorial you mentioned explaining about building a mobile web site. That is you need to support your web site for small screens like mobile phones or tablets.

If you are planing to build a native mobile application, best approach would be to expose core services using RESTful web services.

Comment: If i understood i can create a native mobile application with Zend studio. They actually use Apigility which is a RESTful web service.

Answer (score 0):

using the same database... you have 2 options.... either make a php script to attend the mobile request, or creating a special mysql user that has access to the same database your website uses...